# How to draw a polygon with different line color and rounded corners?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, rounded-corners, polygon

I want to draw a polygon with different line color and rounded corners, but the corners of polygon are not rounded!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=5pt]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);
\coordinate (C) at (3,2);
\coordinate (D) at (1,3);
\coordinate (E) at (-1,2);
\draw[pink] (A) -- (B);
\draw[blue] (B) -- (C);
\draw[red] (C) -- (D);
\draw [green] (D) -- (E);
\draw (E) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This does not give you rounded corners but it does, I suggest, give a much improved result. Essentially the idea is to use a clipping to cut of ragged bits and then to use a triangular cap, with length equal to half of the line width divided by tan 54, to neaten the joins within the pentagon.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=5pt]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}  \coordinate (p\i) at ({18+\i*72}:1);
  \clip (p0) -- (p1) -- (p2) -- (p3) -- (p4) -- cycle;
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xyz{.5*\pgflinewidth/tan(54)}
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 0, evaluate=\j as \k using {int(mod(\j+1,5))}] in {magenta,blue,green,orange,red} \draw [\i, {Triangle Cap[length=\xyz pt]}-{Triangle Cap[length=\xyz pt]}] (p\j) -- (p\k);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: fancy coloured pentagon]

You can add `[rounded corners]` to the `\clip` if you wish, but I did not think the result looked at all good because you only get rounding on the *outer* edge of the line.

For example, adding `[rounded corners=.5*\pgflinewidth]` produces

[image: outer rounded corners]

For real rounding, it may be easier to fill the sectors of the polygon rather than drawing its sides. For example,

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=10pt]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}  \path ({18+\i*72}:1) coordinate (p\i) ++({18+\i*72:-.5*\pgflinewidth}) coordinate (q\i);
  \clip [rounded corners=.5*\pgflinewidth] (p0) -- (p1) -- (p2) -- (p3) -- (p4) -- cycle (q0) -- (q4) -- (q3) -- (q2) -- (q1) -- cycle;
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xyz{.5*\pgflinewidth/tan(54)}
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 0, evaluate=\j as \k using {int(mod(\j+1,5))}] in {magenta,blue,green,orange,red} \path [fill, \i] (p\j) -- (p\k) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

produces

[image: rounded inner and outer corners]

This does not look as neat to me as the non-rounded version, but I can imagine this might be better for certain specialist uses. You might want to fiddle a little with how rounded the corners are for best results - there is probably a trade-off here.

It is not hard to turn these into a `pic` for use in drawing any regular polygon - not just pentagons.

For example, the definition given below makes it possible to write

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {rainbow polygon={sides=6,colours={blue,blue!80!cyan,blue!60!cyan,blue!40!cyan,blue!20!cyan,cyan}}};
  \pic at (2,0) {rainbow polygon={rounded corners=outer,sides=12}};
  \pic at (0,2) {rainbow polygon};
  \pic at (2,2) {rainbow polygon={rounded corners=both,sides=7,colours={red,orange,yellow,green,blue,purple,magenta},line width=8pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

to produce

[image: rainbow polygons]

The `pic` `rainbow polygon` takes a single, optional argument. If specified, this should give customisation options. It only really makes sense to use the `pic`s own keys here, although it will accept other TikZ keys as well.

```
colours={<comma separated list of colours>}
line width=<dimension>
sides=<sensible integer>
rounded corners=<none|inner|outer|both>
size=<dimension>
```

Complete code [use at own risk!]:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,multi,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\newif\ifrainbowpolygon@rounded@outer
\newif\ifrainbowpolygon@rounded@inner
\newcounter{rainbowpolygon@colours}
\setcounter{rainbowpolygon@colours}{0}
\tikzset{%
  pics/rainbow polygon/.style={%
    code={%
      \tikzset{%
        rainbow polygon/.cd,
        defaults,
        #1
      }
      \ifrainbowpolygon@rounded@outer\tikzset{rainbow polygon/clip/.style={rounded corners=.5*\pgflinewidth}}\fi
      \begin{scope}[line width=\rainbowpolygon@linewidth]
        \foreach \i in {0,...,\rainbowpolygon@last}  \path ({90-\rainbowpolygon@eangle+\i*\rainbowpolygon@eangle}:\rainbowpolygon@size) coordinate (p\i) \ifrainbowpolygon@rounded@inner ++({90-\rainbowpolygon@eangle+\i*\rainbowpolygon@eangle}:-.5*\pgflinewidth) coordinate (q\i) \fi ;
         \clip [rainbow polygon/clip] (p0) \foreach \i in {1,...,\rainbowpolygon@last} { -- (p\i) } -- cycle \ifrainbowpolygon@rounded@inner (q0) \foreach \j in {\rainbowpolygon@last,...,1} { -- (q\j) } -- cycle \fi ;
         \ifrainbowpolygon@rounded@inner
           \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using {int(mod(\i+1,\rainbowpolygon@sides))}, evaluate=\i as \j using {int(mod(\i,\therainbowpolygon@colours))}] in {0,...,\rainbowpolygon@last} \path [fill, col\j] (p\i) -- (p\k) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
         \else
           \pgfmathsetmacro\xyz{.5*\pgflinewidth/tan(.5*\rainbowpolygon@iangle)}
           \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \k using {int(mod(\i+1,\rainbowpolygon@sides))}, evaluate=\i as \j using {int(mod(\i,\therainbowpolygon@colours))}] in {0,...,\rainbowpolygon@last} \draw [col\j, {Triangle Cap[length=\xyz pt]}-{Triangle Cap[length=\xyz pt]}] (p\i) -- (p\k);
         \fi
    \end{scope}
    }
  },
  rainbow polygon/.search also={/tikz},
  rainbow polygon/.cd,
  angles/.code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rainbowpolygon@eangle{360/#1}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rainbowpolygon@iangle{180-\rainbowpolygon@eangle}%
  },
  last/.code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\rainbowpolygon@last{int(#1-1)}%
  },
  line width/.store in=\rainbowpolygon@linewidth,
  sides/.store in=\rainbowpolygon@sides,
  sides/.forward to=/tikz/rainbow polygon/angles,
  sides/.forward to=/tikz/rainbow polygon/last,
  size/.store in=\rainbowpolygon@size,
  rounded outer corners/.is if=rainbowpolygon@rounded@outer,
  rounded inner corners/.is if=rainbowpolygon@rounded@inner,
  rounded corners/.is choice,
  rounded corners/none/.style={/tikz/rainbow polygon/.cd, rounded outer corners=false, rounded inner corners=false},
  rounded corners/outer/.style={/tikz/rainbow polygon/rounded outer corners},
  rounded corners/inner/.style={/tikz/rainbow polygon/rounded inner corners},
  rounded corners/both/.style={/tikz/rainbow polygon/.cd, rounded outer corners, rounded inner corners},
  clip/.style={},
  colours/.code={%
    \setcounter{rainbowpolygon@colours}{0}%
    \edef\tempa{#1}%
    \foreach \i in \tempa {
      \edef\tempb{col\therainbowpolygon@colours}%
      \xglobal\colorlet{\tempb}{\i}%
      \stepcounter{rainbowpolygon@colours}%
    }%
  },
  colours/.default={magenta,blue,green,orange,red,gray},
  defaults/.style={%
    line width=5pt,
    sides=5,
    size=10mm,
    rounded corners=none,
    colours,
  },
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic at (0,0) {rainbow polygon={sides=6,colours={blue,blue!80!cyan,blue!60!cyan,blue!40!cyan,blue!20!cyan,cyan}}};
  \pic at (2,0) {rainbow polygon={rounded corners=outer,sides=12}};
  \pic at (0,2) {rainbow polygon};
  \pic at (2,2) {rainbow polygon={rounded corners=both,sides=7,colours={red,orange,yellow,green,blue,purple,magenta},line width=8pt}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=5pt]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}  \coordinate (p\i) at ({18+\i*72}:1);
  \clip (p0) -- (p1) -- (p2) -- (p3) -- (p4) -- cycle;
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xyz{.5*\pgflinewidth/tan(54)}
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 0, evaluate=\j as \k using {int(mod(\j+1,5))}] in {magenta,blue,green,orange,red} \draw [\i, {Triangle Cap[length=\xyz pt]}-{Triangle Cap[length=\xyz pt]}] (p\j) -- (p\k);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=5pt]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}  \path ({18+\i*72}:1) coordinate (p\i);
  \clip [rounded corners=.5*\pgflinewidth] (p0) -- (p1) -- (p2) -- (p3) -- (p4) -- cycle;
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xyz{.5*\pgflinewidth/tan(54)}
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 0, evaluate=\j as \k using {int(mod(\j+1,5))}] in {magenta,blue,green,orange,red} \draw [\i, {Triangle Cap[length=\xyz pt]}-{Triangle Cap[length=\xyz pt]}] (p\j) -- (p\k);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=10pt]
  \foreach \i in {0,...,4}  \path ({18+\i*72}:1) coordinate (p\i) ++({18+\i*72:-.5*\pgflinewidth}) coordinate (q\i);
  \clip [rounded corners=.5*\pgflinewidth] (p0) -- (p1) -- (p2) -- (p3) -- (p4) -- cycle (q0) -- (q4) -- (q3) -- (q2) -- (q1) -- cycle;
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xyz{.5*\pgflinewidth/tan(54)}
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 0, evaluate=\j as \k using {int(mod(\j+1,5))}] in {magenta,blue,green,orange,red} \path [fill, \i] (p\j) -- (p\k) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What wondeful things you can do with TikZ! Could you explain to me this part of the code `evaluate=\j as \k using {int(mod(\j+1,5))}`? Does it means that `j` goes from 1 to 5 while `k` goes from 2 to 5 and then 1? (I don't even try to understand your last example :), but if I could I'd upvote twice!)

Comment: `int` just makes the result an integer. `mod` is modulo. So `\k` will be `\j+1` modulo 5. This bit doesn't touch `\j`. It just calculates `\k` from `\j`. So, if `\j` is the count `from 0`, for example, then `\j` will be 0,1,2,3,4 and `\k` will be 1,2,3,4,0. If `\j` was 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7, then `\k` would be `1,2,3,4,0,1,2` etc. (Obviously, we only have 5 values for the pentagon - but just in theory.)

Comment: thank you, I hadn't understood that `\j` wasn't touched and I know how modulo works but I forgot about 0!