# Edit this code in order to have alternate color edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

Hello I am learning to use control structures and other things in tikz, and i have this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX] in {0,...,10}
        {\ifnum\X=0
            \node [circle,fill=black!40,inner sep=2pt](X\X) at (120:5){};
            \else
            \node [circle,fill=black!40,inner sep=2pt](X\X) at
            ({120-\X*360/12}:5){};
            \draw[black]  (X\LastX) -- (X\X);
            \fi}
        \node[rotate={30+360/12}]  (X11) at ({120+360/12}:5) {$\cdots$};
        \draw[black]  (X10) -- (X11);
        \draw[black]  (X11) -- (X0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

This gave me a cycle, but now I need to color the edges alternating them between red and blue, and I haven't managed to do this. Maybe using two variables or something similar? Can you give me some help please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a polygon with different line color and rounded corners?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321156/how-to-draw-a-polygon-with-different-line-color-and-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a list of colors and select from it with some modulo function. In the simplest case of alternating colors you need modulo 2.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\lstcolors{"red","blue"}
        \foreach \X [remember=\X as \LastX] in {0,...,12}
        {\ifnum\X=0
            \node [circle,fill=black!40,inner sep=2pt](X\X) at (120:5){};
            \else
            \ifnum\X=11
            \node[rotate={30+360/12}]  (X11) at ({120+360/12}:5) {$\cdots$};
            \else
            \node [circle,fill=black!40,inner sep=2pt](X\X) at
            ({120-\X*360/12}:5){};
            \fi
            \draw[color/.evaluated={{\lstcolors}[Mod(\X,2)]}]  (X\LastX) -- (X\X);
            \fi}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I not forgot. :-)

Comment: Thanks, this is very simple, didn't know tikz had a Mod function.

Comment: @Pumuckl is there something missing in the code? If I copy paste it generates an error...

Comment: @J.Rodriguez Do you have an older TeX installation? The `/.evaluated` key is rather new. In older versions you can replace `\draw[color/.evaluated={{\lstcolors}[Mod(\X,2)]}]  (X\LastX) -- (X\X);` by `\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{{\lstcolors}[Mod(\X,2)]}
            \draw[color=\mycolor]  (X\LastX) -- (X\X);`, this should work.

Comment: Ohh, thanks, yes, I installed it a couple years ago, so I tried on Overleaf but also didn't work, now it is ok. Thanks